# inserting object into set fails

Tags: c++, c++11

The following class is present:

```
class Actor {
public:

    float xpos{0};
    float ypos{0};

    Actor(float x, float y);
    ~Actor();
};
```

In the a static function of a management class, I want to create such an actor and insert it into a set:

```
class ActorManager {
private:
    ActorManager();
    static std::set<Actor> actors;
public:
    static void addActor(float x, float y);
}
```

Definition:

```
std::set<Actor> ActorManager::actors = std::set<Actor>();

void ActorManager::addActor(float x, float y) {
    Actor actor(x, y);
    actors.insert(actor); // <--
}
```

With the marked line present, `actors.insert`, the compilation fails. The error states:

```
/usr/lib/c++/v1/__functional_base:56:21: Invalid operands to binary expression ('const Actor' and 'const Actor')
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're not missing anything. You have an extraneous '()' on the end of `actions = std::Set<Actor>()`.

Comment: That seems to be required to initialize the static member, I'm getting an error if I use `{}` instead or leaving them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to overload `operator<` in order to use your class with `std::set` (it needs this in order to sort the elements).

Answer (score 0):

```
bool operator <(const Actor& p1, const Actor& p2){
bool result=false;
if (p1.x<p2.x) 
{
result=true;
}
else if (p1.x==p2.x&&p1.y<p2.y){
result=true;
}
return result;
```

}

//this is the correct way of overloading < operator